# Flash access of undefined property

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

So I am making my first game in flash (more like converting to flash, already have it in JS). I am getting this error:

```
"access of undefined property item"
```

and I have no idea why.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

var Entities:Array = new Array();

//Create player
var Player = new Character();
Player.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - Player.radius;
Player.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - Player.radius;

Entities.push(Player);
stage.addChild(Player);

function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{   
    for each (item in Entities)
    {
        item.update();
    }
}
```

I will be adding many Monsters into entities as well, that's why it's an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are referencing a variable called `item` but you haven't defined it to the compiler.

```
for each (item in Entities)
```

Define (var) the `item` and you will no longer receive the error:

```
for each (var item:Character in Entities)
```

I would recommend using a `Vector` instead of an `Array` (They are basically the same except in a `Vector` every object has to be of the defined type. Then you don't have to cast for the compiler to know what kind of object is in your array.

```
var Entities:Vector.<Character> = new Vector.<Character>();
```

If you do continue to use `Array` - you'll need to cast your items in order to access their properties/methods without a compiler error.

```
Character(item).update(); //since items in arrays are just stored as objects, you need to tell AS3 that this item is a Player class
```

Comment: so it is impossible to put varius types of objects into one array as in js?

Comment: Not al all, arrays are the same in AS3 as JS.   I'm referring to the difference between `Vector` and `Array` in as3.   If you want multiple class types in your array, then you have to use `Array` and not `Vector` (though if they all have a common base class you could use a vector of said base class).   Vectors (in some cases) are faster, and make life easier while coding because you don't have to cast.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, got everything working as I wished now :) also the name of my class is not Player, but Character. Might be confusing for future reference.

Comment: Ah right.  A bit of advice for AS3, recommended practice (though not required so don't feel compelled) is to start all instance names with a lower case letter, and all Class names with an Uppercase letter.  Makes readability easier. (and you'll notice how stackoverflow highlights anything uppercase like it's a class)